# How to mask properties when using HOC's in React?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

My question, while related to a specific use case, is more about a general concept.

I use a library Informed for form management and it uses higher order components to allow creating custom fields. Here's the HOC:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Field from '../components/Field';

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component';
}

const asField = Component => {
  const displayName = getDisplayName(Component);
  Component.displayName = 'Wrapper';
  const AsField = props => <Field component={Component} {...props} />;
  AsField.displayName = displayName;
  return AsField;
};

export default asField;
```

I took this from the [official repo](https://github.com/joepuzzo/informed/blob/master/src/HOC/asField.js). So here's how it's supposed to be used:

```jsx
// Definition
const CustomInput = asField(
  ({
    fieldState: {value},
    fieldApi: {setTouched, setValue},
    forwardedRef
  }) =>
    <input onFocus={() => setTouched()} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} 
           ref={forwardedRef} value={!value && value !== 0 ? '' : value} />
)

// Usage
<CustomInput field="firstName" />
```

So in my case, first, I'm not a big fan of higher order components, and I don't like specifying the field name using `field` prop, I prefer `name`. So with that in mind I create a component that duplicates the functionality of the `asField` HOC and uses `name` instead of `field`:

```jsx
//@flow
import React from 'react'
import {asField} from 'informed'

export const Field = ({children, name, ...props}) => React.createElement(
  asField(children),
  {
    field: name,
    ...props
  }
)
```

Then I use it like this:

```jsx
// Definition
const CustomInput = ({name}) =>
  <Field field={name}>
    {({
      fieldState: {value},
      fieldApi: {setTouched, setValue},
      forwardedRef
    }) =>
      <input onFocus={() => setTouched()} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} 
             ref={forwardedRef} value={!value && value !== 0 ? '' : value} />
    }
  </Field>

// Usage
<CustomInput name="firstName" />
```

This works, but interestingly, it causes something in the state to endlessly update something in the state which blocks the whole UI. The documented way works just fine.

I cannot find anything in my component. The component that `asField` returns is the one that accepts the `field` prop, it gets it through my function along with other props.

What could be the issue here? Did I miss something or is there a problem with the core concept?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong syntax for createElement

instead of `createElement({})` use `createElement(comp, props, children)`

I have made a working code for your case

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class HoC extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <App fromHOC={this.props.fromHOC} field={this.props.field} />;
  }
}

const Field = ({ children, name, ...props }) =>
  React.createElement(HoC, { field: name, ...props }, children);

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        I am getting props {props.fromHOC} <div />
        <div> The name is {props.field} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Field name="New name" fromHOC="YES!!!" />, rootElement);
```

[Full code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2xqvx6qx3r)

For your updated question, I have a probable solution; see it it works

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Text, Form } from "informed";

const Func = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <Form id="simple-form">
      <label htmlFor="name-field">First name:</label>
      {/*(<Text field="name" id="name-field" /> */}
      <Text {...props} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </Form>
  );
};

const HOC = ({ children, name, ...props }) => {
  return React.createElement(Func, { ...props, field: name }, children);
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<HOC name="name" id="name-field" />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Oops, the syntax was indeed wrong, but I typed the code right here, so it wasn't the problem. Unfortunately, there's a little difference between your example and my case: the HOC in my case is more of a wrapper, decorator rather than a component on its own. So it cannot accept properties itself, only the component it returns can accept properties. I'll try to explain that better in my question.

Comment: @JaffParker the code that I present is actually what you need. The `Field` HOC is a wrapper for the actual `HOC` that you are using in your case; i.e. the `asField`. In your case the `Field` takes `name` as a prop to it, and provide its value as `field` to `asField`. The example takes in `name` and provides `field` to the HOC component

Comment: @JaffParker and one thing to always remember while using HOC is that HOC are also ALWAYS a react Component!. They are wrapper to your component; YES! . But they are a react component on their own as well

Comment: I just went to React docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html and it says that a higher order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component. It doesn't accept props or children, only a component. Thus it cannot be a component by definition. Also, before posting my comment I tried your code for my case to make sure I'm not writing nonsense. I will, however, blame it on me not mentioning enough details in the question.

Comment: @JaffParker by "HOC are also ALWAYS a react Component!" I meant it will always return a Component. Every HOC results in a component. I do not know why your code is not working. Instead of `createElement(asField(children),props)` , try using `createElement(asField,props, children)` maybe that will help.
If you want help, make a complete Codesandbox working snippet and update your question with your query, I would be glad to help

Comment: @JaffParker please check the updated answer as well, it might help